# C++11 Virtual template method or Forwarding variadic template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, abstract, variadic-templates

I have this classes:

```
template<class C>
class OperatorsMap
{
    typedef void (C::*voidFunctionType)(void);
    private:
        std::map<long, voidFunctionType> m;
    public:
        template<typename T>
        void Insert(long id, T f1)
            m.insert(std::make_pair(id,(voidFunctionType)f1));

        template<typename O, typename... Args>
        bool SearchAndCall(long id, O *obj, Args&&... args)
        {
            auto mapIter = m.find(id);
            if(mapIter == m.end()) return false;
            auto mapVal = mapIter->second;
            auto Fun = (bool(C::*)(Args ...))(mapVal);
            return (obj->*Fun)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }
};

class IConditionBase
{
    public:
        virtual ConditionInfo GetInfo() = 0;
        virtual void ClearOperators() = 0;
};

template<class C>
class ConditionBase : public IConditionBase
{
public:
    template<typename O>
    ConditionBase(O object){mObject = object;}
    ~ConditionBase(){}

    ConditionInfo GetInfo(){return mInfo;}

    template<typename F>
    void AddOperator(long id, const char* name, F fun)
    {
        mInfo.AddOperatorInfo(name, id);
        mOperators.Insert(id, fun);
    }

    template<typename... Args>
    bool CallOperator(long id, Args&&... args)
    {
        return mOperators.SearchAndCall(id, mObject, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

private:
     ConditionInfo mInfo;
     OperatorsMap<C> mOperators;
     C* mObject;




class ModuleConditionService
{
public:
    ModuleConditionService();
    ~ModuleConditionService();

    template<typename... Args>
    bool EvaluateCondition(long conditionID, long operatorID, Args&&... args)
    {
        bool ret = false;
        IConditionBase* cnd = GetCondition(conditionID);
        switch(conditionID)
        {
            case ID_ACTUAL_TRIP_ID: (static_cast<cndActualTripID>(cnd))->CallOperator(operatorID, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
            default: cout << "Condition with ID " << conditionID << " not found!";
        }
        return ret;
    }

private:
    void AddCondition(IConditionBase* condition);
    IConditionBase *GetCondition(long conditionID);
    vector<IConditionBase*> mConditionContainer;
};

class cndActualTripID : public ConditionBase<cndActualTripID>
{
    public:
        cndActualTripID();
        ~cndActualTripID();
        using ConditionBase<cndActualTripID>::ConditionBase;
        bool operator_Equal(long id);
        bool operator_Greater(long id);
        bool operator_IN(unsigned int idsCount, long ids[]);
};
```

In constructor of `ModuleConditionService` I create condition like this:

```
AddCondition(new cndActualTripID());
```

Then in main I call EvaluateCondition:

```
ModuleConditionService* service = new ModuleConditionService();

long arr[] = {111,122,125,0,129};
bool ret1 = service->EvaluateCondition(1, 10, 5, arr);
bool ret2 = service->EvaluateCondition(1, 9, 89);
bool ret3 = service->EvaluateCondition(1, 8, 122);
```

Everything works fine, but function `EvaluateCondition` isn't quite good I think. Now there is only one condition `cndActualTripID` but when there will be 100 conditions, that type cast `(static_cast<cndActualTripID>(cnd))->CallOperator(operatorID, std::forward<Args>(args)...);` will be very confusing and type cast in .h file isn't good idea I think. It would help, when function `CallOperator` will be in `IConditionBase` like `virtual`, but it is template function :( I must get `args` from argument of `EvaluateCondition` into `SearchAndCall` in `OperatorsMap` but I don't know how. Please can you help me or have you some other idea, how to call `CallOperator` for class `cndActualTripID` (and others) based on `ID` (`ID` is inherited attribute that has every `ConditionBase`). I work with c++11. It is only important parts of code, if is something missing, please tell what and I post it.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: There are no "virtual template methods" here, and rightly so, because no such thing can exist. `type cast in .h file isn't good idea I think` What? Why do you think that? Tell that to everyone who's ever used the CRTP. Casting in an inline method is no more or less valid than casting in an out-of-line definition, whether or not it's in the same file. Maybe you could try to slim the question down further, to focus it, rather than adding more.

Comment: You are trying to do some dangerous things. EvaluateCondition is one, but SearchAndCall is much worse. There is no type safety whatsoever. Consider rethinking your design.

Comment: On your immediate question, you can ditch SearchAndCall and just include a Search. Let the map user do the calling. Search need not be a template. Moreover the map itself need not be a template. It just stores generic pointers to member functions. You cast them to your actual type anyway (dangerous and not recommended if you ask me).

Comment: Thanks n.m. And please how should I redesign my app. Can you direct me to the right path please? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I redesign my program as write n.m. There are no variadic arguments but only one fixed (vector). Now I have class ConditionBaseOperators where I store and call functions. Is it better (more safetly) than before? 
Thanks.

```
template<class C>
        class MODULECONDITIONDOMAIN_API ConditionBaseOperators : public ConditionBase
        {
            typedef bool (C::*Operators)(vector<string>);

            public:
                template<typename O>
                ConditionBaseOperators(O obj){mObject = obj;}
                ~ConditionBaseOperators(){}

                void AddOperator(long id, string name, Operators function)
                {
                    AddOperatorInfo(id, name.data());
                    mOperators.insert(make_pair(id, function));
                }

                bool CallOperator(long id, vector<string> args)
                {
                    bool ret = false;
                    auto it = mOperators.find(id);

                    if(it != mOperators.end())
                    {
                        auto fun = (bool(C::*)(vector<string>))(it->second);
                        ret = (mObject->*fun)(args);
                    }
                    else
                        EERROR("Operator with ID %d not found in module %s", id, GetInfo().GetName().c_str());

                    return ret;
                }

            private:
                 map<long,Operators> mOperators;
                 C* mObject;
        };

class MODULECONDITIONDOMAIN_API ConditionBase : public Wertyz::DomainLayer::Core::DomainObject
        {
            public:
                ConditionBase(){}
                ~ConditionBase(){}

                ConditionInfo GetInfo();
                void SetInfo(ConditionInfo info);
                void SetInfo(long id, string name);
                void AddOperatorInfo(long id, const char* name);

                virtual bool CallOperator(long id, vector<string> args) = 0;

                long VtoL(vector<string> vec, unsigned int idx);
                unsigned long VtoUL(vector<string> vec, unsigned int idx);
                double VtoD(vector<string> vec, unsigned int idx);
                int VtoI(vector<string> vec, unsigned int idx);
                long long VtoLL(vector<string> vec, unsigned int idx);
                vector<long> VtoVL(vector<string> vec);

            private:
                 ConditionInfo mInfo;

        };


class SERVICECORE_API ModuleConditionService
        {
        public:
            ModuleConditionService();
            ~ModuleConditionService();

            bool EvaluateCondition(long conditionID, long operatorID, vector<string> args);

        private:
            void AddCondition(ConditionBase *condition);
            void AddAction(ActionBase* action);

            ActionBase *GetAction(long idx);
            ConditionBase *GetCondition(long conditionID);

            vector<ConditionBase*> mConditionContainer;
            vector<ActionBase*> mActionContainer;

        };

class MODULECONDITIONDOMAIN_API cndActualTripID : public ConditionBaseOperators<cndActualTripID>
            {
                public:
                    cndActualTripID();
                    ~cndActualTripID();

                    using ConditionBaseOperators<cndActualTripID>::ConditionBaseOperators;

                private:
                    bool operator_Equal(vector<string> args);
                    bool operator_Greater(vector<string> args);
                    bool operator_IN(vector<string> args);

                    long GetValue();
            };
```

ModuleCondition.cpp

```
    bool ModuleConditionService::EvaluateCondition(long conditionID, long operatorID, vector<string> args)
    {
        return GetCondition(conditionID)->CallOperator(operatorID, args);
    }
```

cndActualTripID.cpp

```
cndActualTripID::cndActualTripID() : ConditionBaseOperators<cndActualTripID>::ConditionBaseOperators(this)
{
    SetInfo(ID_ACTUAL_TRIP_ID, "ActualTripID");
    AddOperator(1, "Greater", &cndActualTripID::operator_Greater);
    AddOperator(2, "Equal", &cndActualTripID::operator_Equal);
    AddOperator(3, "IN", &cndActualTripID::operator_IN);
}
```